# Java: using WritableRaster.setRect to superimpose an image?

Tags: java, image, image-manipulation, raster

I have been playing with some of the imaging functionality in Java, trying to superimpose one image over another.  Like so:

```
BufferedImage background = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(
    new ByteArrayInputStream(getDataFromUrl(
        "https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif"
    ))
);
BufferedImage foreground = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(
    new ByteArrayInputStream(getDataFromUrl(
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/Sunflower_as_gif_small.gif"
    ))
);

WritableRaster backgroundRaster = background.getRaster();
Raster foregroundRaster = foreground.getRaster();

backgroundRaster.setRect(foregroundRaster);
```

Basically, I was attempting to superimpose this:  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/Sunflower_as_gif_small.gif
[image: flower]

on this: https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif
[image]

The product appears as: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep3XE.png
[image: crappy image]

From the examples I have seen, this seems to be the appropriate method.  Am I missing a step?  Is there a better way to handle this?  Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Your images don't show up for me - Chrome on XP.

Comment: I couldn't figure out why they weren't showing up either, until I looked and found that someone else removed them from my post.  I added links for the images in case this happens again.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to whoever prettied up my (crap?) code.  (mmyers?)

Comment: In the edit history, every revision that is listed has the images, so I don't know why they weren't showing up for a while. And yes, I did format your code (I don't like scrolling to the side if I can help it). :)

Comment: Ah, I see now.  All I saw before was the "___ deleted 24 characters".  I didn't realize I could check it.  When I previewed the post everything looked fine, but for some time afterwords the images simply weren't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I was going about this in all the wrong ways.  This solution outlined on the [Sun forums](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5129834&tstart=0) works perfectly (copied here):

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

class TwoBecomeOne {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage large = ImageIO.read(new File("images/tiger.jpg"));
        BufferedImage small = ImageIO.read(new File("images/bclynx.jpg"));
        int w = large.getWidth();
        int h = large.getHeight();
        int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, type);
        Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(large, 0, 0, null);
        g2.drawImage(small, 10, 10, null);
        g2.dispose();
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("twoInOne.jpg"));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new ImageIcon(image), "",
                                      JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```